# Is this what 'No good deed goes unpunished' means?

Tags: meaning

Is this what 'No good deed goes unpunished' means?

No matter how good you are or how many good deeds you do (or favors you do) for someone, s/he will always find fault with (bitch about) them and will not be truly appreciative.

Could someone please cite an example of this idiom's usage, please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/no_good_deed_goes_unpunished) says, of "no good deed goes unpunished":

> **Beneficial actions often go unappreciated or are met with outright hostility. If they are appreciated, they often lead to additional
>   requests**

It is Wikitionary's last interpretation that I am most familiar with.  For example, suppose you send a generous check to a charity in which you have no interest because a relative of a good friend died.  It is a charity that believes in sending "free gifts" to contributors who send them more than X dollars, which you did.  They send you an object (so ghastly that you would be ashamed to donate it to a charity shop) as a token of their appreciation, plus they solicit you for further contributions for years afterward.  **No good deed goes unpunished.**

This happens, really.

I'm not so familiar with the first definition, but suppose you are out for a walk, and see an empty plastic bottle (clearly tossed by a passing motorist)  defacing someone's lawn.  You go on their lawn to pick it up, and are accused of trespassing.  **No good deed goes unpunished.**

Comment: Good answer. Love the plastic bottle on the lawn. I am most familiar with this term in the sense of the second example: someone comes forward and does a good job on a task that may or may not be part of their actual duties. Either way, because they did such a good job, they receive additional assignments. No good deed goes unpunished. I have a coworker who says this all the time.